# How to resolve the delay problem between two modules in Verilog

Tags: cryptography, verilog

I am trying to implement BIST (Built-in self-test). Test pattern generator(TPG) module generates test patterns using LFSR per posedge clk (`always #1 clk = ~clk`). I am using 32 stage LFSR. Each value of TPG module is sent to the AES encryption module which gives ciphertext after #141 delay. During this #141 delay many of the TPG module outputs are lost. How to solve this problem?

I thought a solution is to store thousand test pattern values in the array (reg [127:0] arr [0:999]) and then send each test pattern to the AES encryption module. Is this a good solution because I think it is making chip memory bigger. If it is then what should I do? The code snippet is given below.

```
wire [127:0] state_byte;

TPG T (clk, rst, bistMode, state_byte);

AES_encryption ENC_TB(key_byte, state_byte, clk, rst, encryptionEnable, state_out_byte, load, ready);
```

codes of TPG module is given below:

```
module TPG (input wire clk, input wire rst, input wire sel, output reg[127:0] valueO);

    integer i;
    reg [31:0] patternGenerate[0:3],temp;


    always @(posedge clk)begin
        if(sel == 1)begin
            if(rst)begin
                valueO = 128'b0;
                temp = 32'b11111111111111111111111111111111;
            end
                else
            begin
                for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)begin
                    temp = {(temp[31] ^ temp[25] ^ temp[22] ^ temp[21] ^ temp[15] ^ temp[11] ^ temp[10] ^ temp[9] ^ temp[7] ^ temp[6] ^ temp[4] ^ temp[3] ^ temp[1] ^ temp[0]), temp[31:1]};
                    patternGenerate[i] = temp;
                end
                valueO = {patternGenerate[3],patternGenerate[2],patternGenerate[1],patternGenerate[0]};
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: You can simply add `enable` signal to your TPG in order to generate next value only every 141 clock cycles. What is more, BISTs typically test crypto core using only a few values, because you also have to precompute (e.g. using software implementation) and store correct result.

Comment: Sir well I will add enable signal but how could I set 141 delays, please explain. Thank in advance.

Comment: You should explain your algorithm a bit better. i.e, what do you do with the encrypted data, why do you need to store all the patterns, ..... On the side note, you should use non-blocking assignment for `value0` and re-think use of `temp`, it should not  be reset at  'rst', or you have to figure out how to use nba there as well.